# How to recursively parse fields of Class

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have instance of class which contain many fields of another obfuscated classes witch contains many fields too etc.

One of fields with String type contain some useful data in value with prefix "xxxyyyzzz" for example.
How to recursively parse all class and inner classes fields?

Write some function but it too much recursive, parse same class, and I get StackOverflowError

```
fun parseFields(obj: Any) {
        val clazz = obj::class.java
        val fields = clazz.declaredFields

        for (field in fields) {
            field.isAccessible = true

            val value = field.get(obj)
            println(value)

            if (value is String && value.startsWith("xxxyyyzzz")) {
                // we found it!
                println(value)
            }

            if (value != null) {
                parseFields(value)
            }
        }
    }
```